# How to implement faceted search with cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a kinda faceted search task to my domain model.

I have a graph that consists of two parts:

1. `(:TAG)`'s hierarhical tree with `-[:IS_A]->` relations between parent tags and it's child(s). Note, that each banch of the tree has different levels of depth.
   Every `(:TAG)` node has unique `"name"` (String) propery
2. Individual `(:IMG)` nodes, that have unique `"name"` (String) and `"href"` (String) properties.
3. Every `(:IMG)` is connected to at least one `(:TAG)` with the relation `(:TAG)-[:DESCRIBES]->(:IMG)`, but there could be `(:TAG)` nodes that don'c connect with any of `(:IMG)` nodes.
   [image]

I need to be able to tell any amount of tag's "names" and to be responsing all intersecting images nodes, but with following logic:
If every two `(:TAG)` nodes has similar parent `(:TAG)` node, so I need to response images conencted to both of them,
else (if they have different parent `(:TAG)` node), so I need to response only images that connect to both of them at the same time.

--

What I already know:

1. If I want to get images that are conencted to only intersecting tags (tag1 or tag2 or tag3), so I need the following query:

```
MATCH
(img:IMG)<-[*]-(:TAG {name:'Tag Name A'}),
(img:IMG)<-[*]-(:TAG {name:'Tag Name B'}),
(img:IMG)<-[*]-(:TAG {name:'Tag Name C'})
RETURN img
```

2. If I want to get images that are connected to every tag (tag1 and tag2 and tag3), so I need the following query:

```
MATCH (img:TEST_01_Img)
WHERE
(img)<-[*]-(:TAG {name:'Tag Name A'})
OR
(img)<-[*]-(:TAG {name:'Tag Name B'})
OR
(img)<-[*]-(:TAG {name:'Tag Name C'})
RETURN img
```

And I think have to somehow combine these two methods with (if...else) logic of combining results if images have same tag's parent and intersecting them if they have different tag's parents.

Maybe I need to use [Conditional Cypher Execution](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/cypher-execution/conditionals/), but I have no idea how, cuz I'm very new to this.

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can combine match [pattern] with where [pattern]. Example:

```
// Tagged A and B
MATCH (img)<-[*]-(:TAG {name:'Tag Name A'})
WHERE (img)<-[*]-(:TAG {name:'Tag Name B'})

// Tagged A but not B
MATCH (img)<-[*]-(:TAG {name:'Tag Name A'})
WHERE NOT (img)<-[*]-(:TAG {name:'Tag Name B'})
```

See Using Patterns in Where (https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/where/#query-where-patterns)